# option is working but its not echoing for some reason

Tags: php, html

i have an option that is taking its options from mysql then it echo the tab the user chose when but its not echoing it

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="work_place">
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $category = $row["category"];
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category;?>"><?php echo $category;?>
        </option>
<?php
} 
?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
<?php
$post = (isset($_POST['work_place'])) ? $_POST['work_place'] : '';
echo $post;
?>
```

idk why but its not echoing the post $post

picture of the problem not echoing
[image]

Comment: Do you submit form first? Do `var_dump($_POST)` instead

Comment: Because URL query parameters show up in `$_GET`, not `$_POST`…!?

Comment: From the image it seems that you are using GET method

Comment: Guys.. the form itself is post..

Comment: Are you sure `method="post"` is exactly that, no hidden characters or anything in there that would make the browser disregard that attribute and submit the form via GET instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$post = (isset($_GET['work_place'])) ? $_GET['work_place'] : '';
```

insted of doing that:

```
$post = (isset($_POST['work_place'])) ? $_POST['work_place'] : '';
```